# How can we make this hypothetical question clearer?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[After an unintended harassement, should the recruiter contact the candidate again if they think they've found the right offers?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/89264/26826)

This question is on hold as being unclear. Is it because it is a hypothetical question, or because it asks about the feeling? If the latter is true, then would rewriting

> What would X think?

to

> Would doing this make X feel...?

make it clearer?

Comment: I don't see how the second phrasing helps. The question is basically asking people to guess how someone might think/feel in a hypothetical situation. I'm not sure that kind of question can be answered here. You indicated that you are "in a situation similar to the recruiter". I suspect you have a better sense of how the candidate would think or feel than anyone here could.

Comment: Reading the current version and the title I simply have no idea what kind of situation and question it's describing. Are you basically asking about a "recruiter who called wolf" scenario?

Comment: @Lilienthal no, the recruiter is sincere. So there is no way a candidate be the best fit for a company that they want them so much, and the recruiter trying to negotiate with any price?

Comment: @Ooker I still don't understand what you're trying to ask, sorry.

Comment: Honestly your "recruiter" comes across as creepy at best. I can see the parallels with a stalker proposing to a girl to make out with him, and wondering what the right "offer" would be after she repeatedly told him she was not interested. Even without drawing that parallel, it is still not clear to me what you are asking for. What would the candidate think and what should the recruiter do are way too broad, and can best be answered (albeit somewhat bluntly) by, "why are you asking *us*, ask them", which is a synonym (for me, anyway) for "unclear what you are asking".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see salvaging this question is to write it similar to this:

> I am a recruiter and misspoke in a way that a prospective candidate took offense. The candidate has made it clear that she no longer wishes me to contact her but my client is very interested in bringing the candidate on.  How can I set this situation right for my company, the client, and the candidate?

Comment: Lol, actually I'm not a recruiter, and not doing anything wrong to my best knowledge and honesty. But yes I agree with you. Can I simply replace *I am a recruiter* to *imagine a recruiter*?

Comment: there is a standard that reads something like: *We expect questions here to be problems you "Actually" face.*  We define actually as being a problem that is realistic that you "Could" be facing and ask the question as if you were facing it.

What is the actual problem you are trying to find the answer to? Ask that question as though you need to find the answer to it.

Comment: yes, I am facing it, and actually it's a personal issue. However, I see that my situation is pretty much the same with the highly welcomed question linked at the top of my question, I would like to ask it as if it is a workplace issue, where relationships are generally not personal, to see how professionals deal with it. Is this acceptable?

Comment: So what role in this question do you have?  are you the one that was harassed?

Comment: @Ooker - Is your question how you can have a personal relationship with someone you met as a candidate?  How to interest them personally would be off topic.  How to address the issue with your company would be.

Comment: no, definitely not to establish a personal relationship to any candidate. My role is similar to the recruiter, but the only intention is to deliver the best to the "candidate"

Comment: @Ooker - Is the current version more acceptable maybe?

Comment: Yesss, *misspoke*. Anyhow, I'm still not a recruiter. Would not mentioning that makes my question less real?

Comment: No but I doubt the answers are going to be very helpful to your real situation but I think that question would be accepted and answered

Comment: so it's safe to start with *imagine a recruiter*?

Comment: No no Imagine.  Just ask the question as if it applies to you and you want the answer.